# Renew cridentials for AmazonKinesisClient using AWSSDK

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

Im creating a on-prem application in .Net  that consumes a kinesis stream.
How do I write a method that can renew the cridentials for my KinesisClient (They are only valid for 1 hour) without re-create the client itself. Is that possible? Or am I approching this the wrong way?

This is the factory class that im using to produce the client.

```
public static AmazonKinesisClient CreateKinesisClient(BasicAWSCredentials credentials, string roleArn, string roleSessionName, RegionEndpoint region, LogWriter logWriter)
    {
        try
        {
            var stsClient = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(credentials);
            var ownerRoleReq = new AssumeRoleRequest
            {
                RoleArn = roleArn,
                RoleSessionName = roleSessionName
            };
            var ownerRoleResp = stsClient.AssumeRoleAsync(ownerRoleReq).Result;

            logWriter.LogInfo<AmazonKinesisClient>("Role taken:" + ownerRoleResp.AssumedRoleUser);
            return new AmazonKinesisClient(ownerRoleResp.Credentials, region);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           logWriter.LogError<AmazonClientFactory>(e.Message,e);
           throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with saving the latest record id in a concurrent dictionary and while re-creating the client injecting the dictionary containing the latest id for each shard in the KinesisStream.

```
 private string CreateShardIteratorRequestWithSequenceNumber(Shard shard, string sequenceNumber)
    {
        var iteratorRequest = new GetShardIteratorRequest()
        {
            ShardId = shard.ShardId,
            StreamName = _streamName,
            ShardIteratorType = ShardIteratorType.AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER,
            StartingSequenceNumber = sequenceNumber
        };
        return GetShardIterator(iteratorRequest);
    }
```